# how can i find what version of rails my app is running on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, config

I am trying to run an old rails app, but I am receiving this error after calling `$ rails server`:

```
uninitialized constant AppGenerator::Config
Did you mean?  RbConfig
```

I am brand new to Rails, and I really don't know what this means/where to start. The app is supposedly built on 2.3.8. My computer says I have 2.4.1 and 2.3.18 installed.

I would like to know if I should install 2.3.8, or if I should upgrade to the latest version? Also I don't understand the error that is coming up, where should I look in the app to fix this - or is this a Rails problem?

Answer (score 3):

Verify the version your project is built type `bundle show` inside it. It's gonna show all the gems and your respective versions.

And to check the rails version just type `rails -v` in your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The gemfile in the app folder should tell you what version of rails it is.

You can use `bundle update` to update the version or if you have a newer version and want an older version, do `gem uninstall rails` and then `gem install rails -v "version number"` for example, `gem install rails -v 2.3.8`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the rails version on `Gemfile`.

Try the command `rake about` to see the application environment.

I would suggest to have your environment setup same on the `Gemfile`, your application might have compatibility issues if you use a lower version.

Comment: It seems like my makefile is having issues. The rakefile exists, but no commands are going through. I received the following error when I tried rake about: 

rake about
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)